# How to set brighter colors in Cucumber's console output?

Tags: cmd, cucumber, ansi-colors

Default Cucumber console colors are too faded. How to change the colors to their brighter analogs?

Answer (score 1):

There's a page on the [cucumber wiki](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber/wiki) that details how to modify the [console colors](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber/wiki/Console-Colours).

Comment: I've tested it already through and through with no result. I also tried to set Windows color names like Lime, Chartreuse, Green Yellow. Unfortunately, only errors are thrown.

Comment: The cucumber wiki appears to be defunct.